# Determining which statements are true for all invertible $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is the problem:

> Determine which of the following statements are true for all invertible $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$:
>
> A. $(A+A^{−1})^7=A^7+A^{−7}$
>
> B. $(I_n−A)(I_n+A)=In−A^2$
>
> C. $AB=BA$
>
> D. $A^6B^5$ is invertible
>
> E. $A+I_n$ is invertible
>
> F. $(A+B)(A−B)=A^2−B^2$

So far, I believe that all except choice B are false. However, only selecting choice B as true is incorrect.

Here is my rationale for each statement:

A is incorrect as I have found a counter example with the $2\times 2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}1 &2 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$.

C is incorrect as matrix multiplication is not commutative

D is incorrect as matrix multiplication must occur with matrices with the same column as row number of matrix $A$ and $B$ respectfully

E is incorrect as if $A$ were the $2 \times 2$ matrix $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0\\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ the resulting matrix could not be invertible

F is incorrect by the same logic as my explanation for C

I'd appreciate any guidance on this problem!

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are invertible $n\times n$ matrices, then $(A^6B^5)^{-1}=(B^{-1})^5(A^{-1})^6$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D) is true as already pointed out. For A) I would use the simpler example of diagonal matrix $A$ with diagonal entries $(1,0,..,0)$.

For C) you cannot just say matrix multiplication is not commutative. You have to give  specific example of invertible matrices $A$ and $B$ with  $AB \neq BA$. I will leave that to you. This would also answer F).

B) is true.

For E) take $A=-I_n$.

Answer (score 2):

You are given that $A$ and $B$ are $n \times n$ matrices, they can be multiplied together, hence $D$ is correct as well.  We can take the determinant and see that it is indeed invertible.